# Unknown uv-layer MeshUVLoopLayer("NGon Face-Vertex") appears while iterating an objects uv layers

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I "discovered" a uv-layer called "NGon Face-Vertex".

My goal was to get get rid of all other uv-layers except the active one.
So i wrote:

```
for layer in list(C.object.data.uv_layers):
   print("layer",layer)
   if not layer.active:
      C.object.data.uv_layers.remove(layer)
```

This code throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 4, in <module>
RuntimeError: Error: Texture layer 'NGon Face-Vertex' not found
```

So i wonder where does this layer come from?
Tried it with the default cube and blender version 2.82.8
Thought you people might find it interesing.

Here are some before/after screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Oh and this is how i do it now to circumvent this misterous layer:

```
for key in C.object.data.uv_layers.keys():
   layer = C.object.data.uv_layers[key]
   if not layer.active:
      C.object.data.uv_layers.remove(layer)
```

Edit: added working code to remove all layers but the active one

Comment: You fell into the good old trap of modifying a list whilst iterating over it. This is not a blender related problem but a python (or even programming at large) problem. You can either iterate from last index to index 0, using  `for i in range(len(my_list), -1, -1):` or `while my_list:`

Comment: Also FYI, the solution you used is also a good one to avoid this problem. In this case you are using a generated list of all the layer names, but it is independant of what happens to said layers afterwards. So there is no problem removing them from memory. To avoid any `KeyError` you can use the dictionary `get` as in `layer = C.object.data.uv_layers.get(key)`. If the layer doesn't exist, the variable will be `None`  Next line would then be `if layer is not None and layer.active:`

Comment: Oh no, i thought i'd got me covered with generating a shallow copy of the array by passing it to the list constructor: list(C.object.data.uv_layers). Either way, i am still wondering where this NGon Face-Vertex reference comes from? Do i maybe access one from another object because of my failed iteration?

Comment: For example using: `for non_active_layer in [layer for layer in C.object.data.uv_layers if not layer.active]:` as the beginning of the for loop. and then removing it `C.object.data.uv_layers.remove(non_active_layer)` leads to the same error.

Comment: I can't say I ever saw this uv layer name anywhere. Maybe one of the add-ons you are using automatically adds uv layers ? It doens't appear in the interface when you expand an object's uv maps ?

Comment: Added some screenshots. I now realize that the code does not leave the active layer but UVMap.001 as the one that's clicked on. I have to compare with `C.object.data.uv_layers.active`! The error with the misterious uv_layer still appears though.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132670/how-to-find-and-delete-extra-uv-layers-on-many-objects