# How do you remove a uv map by index with python?

Tags: python, uv

Can  delete a UV Map / Texture, via

```
bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_remove()
```

But how can I delete a UV Map by it's Index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Set the active index,**

Similarly to materials and other lists where the active and active index can be set.

Example in python console.  The 3rd UV map is active

```
>>> C.object.data.uv_layers.active_index
2
```

Change instead to second (index 1)

```
>>> C.object.data.uv_layers.active_index = 1
```

Operator removes the active UV map

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_remove()
{'FINISHED'}
```

See also [How to find and delete extra UV layers on many objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132670/how-to-find-and-delete-extra-uv-layers-on-many-objects) : can remove directly using the `remove` API method.

```
>>> C.object.data.uv_layers.remove(C.object.data.uv_layers[1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!